# Is the electric current delayed

Tags: current, delay, electrical, speed

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHXvOz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

-Suppose that the distance between "D1" and "D2" is too large.

-Does "D2" give a delayed response compared to "D1"?

Comment: I would say yes. For that purpose the conductors should be though of as wave guides, while the wave is propagated with a finite speed.

Comment: no, electrons flow from negative terminal to the positive terminal of the power supply, so D2 will light first

Comment: @jsotola "no" to what? And this is way too simplified. Electrons in the conductors are set in motion by electric field which is propagated as a wave.

Comment: @EugeneSh, same thing that you are saying "yes" to

Comment: @jsotola, if we take the schematic arrangement as indicative of the physical arrangement, the ground wire is longer than the positive voltage wire.

Comment: @jsotola But you say there will be delay. And I say there will be... Ah got it, you say there will be delay in the opposite order.

Comment: @Jundullah The slow LED response will conceal any lightspeed-delay, unless the wires are hundreds of feet long.  We CANNOT DETECT the delayed response, since the speed of typical LEDs is ~100 nanoseconds, while the circuit-delay is from EM waves, roughly 1000x faster.  (Try laser diodes instead.  Then it becomes possible to measure the fast pulse-edge timing.)

Comment: @jsotola actually electrons are irrelevant here, since propagation delays would be the same for thin tubes of salt water, or even for acidic proton-conductors. Any waves coming from the signal-source will fly outward along both the pos and the neg wires at the same time.  That's how 2-wire transmission lines work, regardless of charge-carrier polarity or signal polarity.  D1 would light first, if the connecting wire is shorter.  (perhaps use comm laser-diodes and 40GHz Finisar modules to perform nanosecond measurements on centimeter wire lengths.)

Comment: When it gets too large , you end up being able to harvest  a dim LED even without a battery due to induction of line fields.  ;)

Comment: "too large" means we die of old age before the second LED lights up.  Just string your wire-loop around the galactic border!

Comment: look -> https://www.livescience.com/53889-electric-current.html

Comment: This is confusing. If there is supposed to be a transmission line in the circuit, please edit the schematic to show where. Is it just one series delay line between D1 and D2, or is it a two wire transmission cable (supply and ground return) between D2 and the rest of the circuit? I think that is the key difference between the “yes” and “no” answers, how this ambiguous question is interpreted.

Comment: You should look up what transmission lines and reflections are.

Comment: I mostly agree with @wbeaty, I would add that it actually depends on which connexion you make last in the real world.  If we connect the '-' last, then D2 see the voltage difference first, if we connect the '+' last, then D1 gets the voltages difference first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case shown, with both diodes near the power supply but with a very long wire between them, there will be no delay. However, in the case shown below, there will be a delay:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fveorZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The reason there's a delay in this case and not in the other is related to the fact that information must travel at the speed of light or slower, so the information that the power supply has been turned on has to travel through the Extremely Long Cable™ at no faster than the speed of light.

For further research, I recommend websearching the term "transmission line".

Comment: What is the result of comparing electric current with water? @Hearth

Comment: @Jundullah You mean the hydraulic analogy? Well, in water, pressure changes propagate at the speed of sound, so consider that the current flow at the end of a long pipe would be delayed relative to the beginning of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

No, for an ideal diode (or LED) there is no capacitance or inductance and the current through both is equal. (and in the ideal world wires are made out of superconductors)

For a real world diode there is a slight amount of parasitic capacitance and inductance that might cause a slight difference if you're looking at very small timescales, for most applications this would be negligible.

If you wanted to analyze this for a distance that is 'too far' then model it as a transmission line ( a long line of RC or RLC filters) or insert the calculated of resistance of the wire or trace between diodes between diodes

Comment: The question asks us to "Suppose that the distance between "D1" and "D2" is too large." This means (at least to me) we can no longer assume the lumped circuit approximation holds.

Comment: @neil_UK Sorry, I'm going to relearn the correct grammar one of these days!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, D1 will emitt light a very short time earlier than D2. The current flowing through D1 will have to load the the very long cable's capacity before the same current will flow through both LEDs.